# Periodically sending the same request with RxJava2

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

So, I have an API call which returns a list of Dog breeds,
and another call that takes the `dogBreedIds` and fetches dog names for each of these breed IDs. 
In `onNext`, I add these dog names into a list, 
and in the `doOnComplete`, I display these in a recycler view.

Both `getDogBreeds` and `getDogNames` return an `Observable<List>` is an example of rx chain i accomplish this with:

```
petsRepository.getDogBreeds()
            .map { breeds ->
                breeds.items.map {
                    it.id
                }
            }
            .flatMapIterable { listOfIds -> listOfIds }
            .flatMap { dogId -> getDogNames(dogId) }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnComplete { displayDogNames() }
            .subscribe(this::onDogNamesLoaded, this::onError)
```

What I'm trying to do is, to re-trigger this whole process **once in every 60 seconds**, and then, compare the response list with the first response I have and display it to the user if the response list has differences **(this part is perhaps irrelevant)**

I have tried to use `Observable.interval()`, however I could not succeed in doing this. I have checked plenty of examples with no success.

Please let me know if I should be providing more information on this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could go for interval like this:

```
Observable.interval(0, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .flatMap {
                    petsRepository.getDogBreeds()
                }.map {...}
```

The rest should remain pretty much the same.

As for the displaying part - I'm going to assume you're using RecyclerView(correct me if not). If so, then use ListAdapter, DiffUtils will handle displaying differences in lists.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you r2rek! I was trying to put all the logic within the first flatMap there, hence i failed.

Comment: Actually on second note, the .doOnComplete{} is not invoked for some reason, any ideas?

Comment: Putting your operators inside the first flatMap is actually the right approach if you want to get the onComplete callback, since `Observable.interval` is an infinite stream and won't ever complete.

Comment: paxcow, doOnComplete is not called since this is pretty much an infinite stream. You should probably move  ```displayDogNames()``` to onNext(like I said, DiffUtils would take care of checking the differences between the lists